# Why is the primitive cohomology real?

Tags: homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

We let $P^n(X,\mathbb{C}) = H^n_o(X,\mathbb{C})$ and $P^{p,q}(X) = H^{p,q}_o(X,\mathbb{C})$ denote primitive cohomology.

[image]

My question is why $P^{p,q}(X)\subset P^r(X,\mathbb{R})$, s.t. we can use the basis of $P^r(X,\mathbb{R})$ to represent the basis elements of $P^{p,q}(X)$ (as I highlighted)?

Reference: O'Wells' complex analysis on complex manifold p.208

Comment: Dolbeault classes of type $(p,q)$ with $p\ne q$ will never be real (as the conjugate of a $(p,q)$-form is a $(q,p)$-form.  Wells is just writing linearly independent (complex) forms as linear combinations of basis real $r$ forms ($p+q=r$). The coefficients $\omega_{\alpha\sigma}$ are complex numbers.

Comment: @TedShifrin that makes sense